# How could i develop 2 version of the same software with just small changes?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am developing a Java software for a website and i actually need to build two different versions of it but just in some classes.

The version A has 2 packages and 10 classes.
The version B is the same as A but has 1 more package with 3 class files on it and a modified Main class to instantiate the new packages.

What is the best way to achieve this with Maven? Please consider that in a scale out of 10, i think i know 4 about this software as i am new with it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a version parameter in a properties file. Keep it as A or B as specified by you.

At code side, keep all the packages in the same jar. You just need to update the main method where you can read the value for version from the properties file and accordingly instantiate the objects for package 3 as well , in case of version B. Else it will not. Like this you would require to change in main method only.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know git?

Git is the perfect tool you need. It is a version control system that allows you to manipulate the versions of your software. It's very simple and easy to learn. Most corporations use that for both simple and huge projects.

You can see their homepage https://git-scm.com/.
You can download in https://git-scm.com/downloads. You can learn how to use the tool here in this complete tutorial https://git-scm.com/docs.

If you want to skip the tutorial of all commands of git, just know this ones and search for them:

### -git status

### -git add [file]

### -git commit

### -git branch

### -git difftool

### -git log

Thank you! I hope I could help you

Comment: I know and i'm using git, but maybe i'm missing something to work with 2 similar branches...